# Photo printing service API for my photo sharing website

Tags: api

I am triying to find a good photo printing service that will allow users of my photo sharing website to order print versions of the photos that they have uploaded to my site. I have looked at Snapfish and Shutterfly but wondered if there was any others that would do this. As far as I can tell snapfish have an affiliate program that pays a percentage for referrals to their site and an API called publisher which lets developers create apps that use photos already on the snapfish site but cant seem to see a way in which users of my site would be able to print on snapfish (without re-uploading to snapfish). What I want to be able to do is the following -

1. User uploads to my website
2. Clicks a 'Print' button
3. User gets redirected to 3rd party print service along with the photos they want to print
4. User signs in / registers with 3rd party service
5. Sees the photos they selected from my site
6. Completes order process

Does anyone know of a service which will allow me to do this? Does snapfish or shutterfly work in this way? I know flickr can do this but I guess Snapfish are using the Flickr API to retrieve photos. I dont want users to have to download from my site and then re-upload to snapfish for example to print.

Any suggestions?